Fastendpoints Validator with injected constructor
I'm trying Fastendpoints  for organize endpoints in a .net8 web-api project. I have configured validators as follows


Issue is when the app starts in local environment it shows the following fail message. But the validation fires successfully. Anyone has idea about the shown fail message. Does it have any effect.

I also tried to use fluent validation and configure upon startup like this. But then the error is missing but validation didn't fire.


public class Validator : AbstractValidator<MalaysiaForecastRequest>
public class DemographicDataValidator : AbstractValidator<DemographicData>

Anyone have an idea whether

Reason for fail message when using fastendpoint validator.
Is it possible to use fluent validation with the combination of fastendpoints.

Thanks in advance.

i tried to reproduce your issue with this code but was not successful. if you can show me how to replicate the problem by updating my code and adding it to your question (or a new pastebin), i can have a further look.

It only happens when you have a sub validators
public class Validator : Validator
{
public Validator(IStringLocalizer localizer)
{
RuleFor(x => x.CountryId).NotEmpty().WithMessage(localizer["Countryid"].Value);
RuleFor(p => p.DemographicData).SetValidator(new DemographicDataValidator(localizer));
}
}
public class DemographicDataValidator : Validator
{
public DemographicDataValidator(IStringLocalizer localizer)
{
}
}

public DemographicDataValidator(){} but if you add parameterless constructor it disappears. However validation works fine even with fail message.

https://pastebin.com/YnnAM8Lw

i was able to reproduce the issue and a fix has been implenented in v5.28.0.3-beta. give that a go and report back pls.
